# apache ,php, error 404,object not found

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

guys i have a problem its not working or i don't know how to call it

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1h PHP/5.4.31

the following is done ..

http://localhost:800/xampp/test.php

but i can't accesss any of my code or its not running is it windows 8 causing problems

plzzz help

everything is running mysql apache tomcat...

Comment: folder path of the files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your url is wrong. Localhost port is 80 or 8080. You can check with this url:

http://localhost/xampp/test.php

or

http://localhost:8080/xampp/test.php